# Creating one's own Programs folder under windows?

Tags: windows

Windows (I use 7 and XP, professional) creates the `C:\Program Files\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\` folders by default. I am thinking of creating some folders of my own under `C:\` to install my programs (on next format) - so I can edit configs etc without UAC prompts and so I can see in one glance what I installed my self and what came with the OS - etc

Is it a good idea ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: I see no problems with creating an extra folder. (A bit like /usr/local/ or /opt/ on unix). An alternative would be to install to %program files%, the move the files and create a NTFS junction.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to disable UAC.

Comment: @Slaks : no - it's annoying sometimes but the main reason is it looks more orderly to me this way

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - What you want is working around a security feature within Windows, either disable the security feature, or live with it.  What you want to do is a bad idea, it makes you, vulerable to exploits if they exist with those installed programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing at all wrong with your plan, I do this myself, I have my own Program Files folder on my 1TB `D:` drive for programs that are big and don't need to be on my SSD `C:` drive.

The only issue may be is when you are installing programs it will always default to the original location, but if you just pay attention you can just change the path as you install your programs.

Comment: Or edit the registry.

Comment: @tr4656 I ran in to MANY compatability issues with poorly written programs that expect the path of `%ProgramFiles%` to be `C:\Program Files`. You can do it if you want, but I recommend leaving the default path as-is. Also that defats the second reason the OP's wants this *"and so I can see in one glance what I installed my self and what came with the OS"*

Comment: Yes, there are issues with broken programs. They also break if you use a non-english windows install, or just add their own directories. But the real fix is to upgrade to software which got written after windows NT got released. All software since should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

program installed on program file folder by default.

but several of them don't attention to default standard location  that Microsoft recommended and you can change it manually under installation Steps.

please uninstall and install them again in your Program Files.

Comment: few of them may be portable and you can move them manually and update shortcuts.